# rows to column conversion in mysql form joining table not same table

Tags: php, mysql

I have two table 
**Table Doctor**

```
docid|name|specialization|userid
    1| amit|1|1
-----|-----|-|---|
    2|sumit|2|1
-----|-----|-|---|
    3|xyz  |2|2
-----|-----|-|---| 
   3| xyzx |3|4
-----|-----|-|-- |
```

**Table user**

```
uid|fname|
---|-----|
  1| aaa |
  2| pppp|
 3 | cccc|
```

**Table specialization**

```
sid|specialization|
-----|-----|
   1| PHY|
-----|-----|
   2| SUR|
-----|-----|
   3| CARDEO|
```

and so on in all tabbles....

I want value like

```
uid|fname|PHY|SUR|CARDEO| dynamic specialization|
---|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
1     aaa|   1 |0|0|0|
---|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
2     ppp|   1 |1|0|0|
---|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
3      ccc| 0  |1|1|0|
```

I want user wise doctor specialization wise count for all users.

Comment: this is not duplicate i want dynamic column on joining table not same table

Comment: what is useris in table doctor ? should i relate uid or docid? could you be more specific..!!!

Comment: useris is misspelled that is userid , You relate userid of doctor table to uid on user table